# Nvidia Geforce GT630 resolution problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, resolution

I installed the drivers but the maximum resolution I can get is 1360x768. Can I get to 1920x1080? On Windows it worked fine.
Edit: I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my blog, [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html),

You can do the following

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1600x900_60.00"
sudo xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

1. First command creates a new mode with resolution 1600x900
2. Second command makes it available for use, with display (in this case VBOX0)
3. Third command selects the newly added mode as the display resolution for the specified display
4. **To change this to any custom resolution,** just replace 1600 with the width you want and 900 with the height you want.

This worked for me.